# increase font size of grid in extjs

Tags: datagrid, fonts, extjs, grid

How do you increase the font size of a datagrid in ext-js?

I have tried changing the font-size property in both ext-all.css and in xtheme-blue.css but neither one seemed to work.

For example:

.x-grid3-row td, .x-grid3-summary-row td{
    font:normal 21px/23px arial, tahoma, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of altering the base CSS for ExtJS have you thought about altering the config of the editor/datagrid compontent itself?

[bodyCssClass:'yourclass'](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Panel.html#cfg-Ext.Panel-bodyCfg)
nb.[*see also*](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Panel.html#cfg-Ext.Panel-bodyCssClass)

Comment: Can I get some help on how to do this?  I can't find anything in the Sencha documentation.

Comment: Check the links in the answer, they will take you to the documentation

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add `!important` to force your css to override extjs's css.

Comment: I thought by editing the ext-all.css file I was overriding the extjs css?

Comment: Your actually replacing (not overriding) the extjs css. This will create a big pain in the butt when you try to upgrade the extjs library, so you should consider Ergo's answer.